# How can I add a locally created git repository to my GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I was wondering if it's possible to create a git repository locally first, by using `git init` and then adding it to my GitHub account? Instead of first creating the repository and then cloning it locally.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+connect+existing+directory

Answer (score 1):

1. [Create a new GitHub repository](https://github.com/new) (without any initialized files)
2. Copy the repository's URL
3. Run `git remote add origin URL`
4. Run `git push --all origin`